# Replacing values of a computer based test result dataset using answer key

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, dataset

My data set is taken from a computer based test, a sample is given below.

```
x<-data.frame(rbind(c("A","C","A","B","A"),
                    c("M","M","M","M","M"),
                    c("M","M","M","M","M"),
                    c("C","C","A","C","A"),
                    c("C","C","B","C","A"),
                    c("A","C","A","C","B")))

colnames(x)<-c("q1","q2","q3","q4","q5")
rownames(x)<-c("key","c1","c2","c3","c4","c5")
    q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
key  A  C  A  B  A
c1   M  M  M  M  M
c2   M  M  M  M  M
c3   C  C  A  C  A
c4   C  C  B  C  A
c5   A  C  A  C  B
```

Columns represent questions and rows represents candidates. 
First row is the answer key. M stands for unanswered. 
I need to replace the values such that Ms are replaced with "NA" and right answers with 1 and wrong answers with 0. 
EX. For q1 the right answer is "A" so the value for candidate 3 , "C"  has
to be replaced with 0 since the answer is wrong.

The final dataset should look like this

```
      q1   q2   q3   q4   q5
key    A    C    A    B    A
c1  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
c2  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
c3     0    1    1    0    1
c4     0    1    0    0    1
c5     1    1    1    0    0
```

Replcaing Ms are fairly simple.

```
x[x=="M"]<-NA
```

But I am finding it difficult to replace the other values in a single step.

```
x<-as.matrix(x)
```

Converted to matrix since dataframe throws an error 
"Error in Ops.factor(left, right) : level sets of factors are different"

```
for(i in 2:nrow(x)){
  for( j in 1:ncol(x))
  {
    ifelse(x[i][j]==x[1][j],x[i][j]<-1,x[i][j]<-0)
  }}
```

This for loop is only replacing the values of the first column.

```
    q1  q2  q3  q4  q5 
key "A" "C" "A" "B" "A"
c1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
c2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
c3  "0" "C" "A" "C" "A"
c4  "0" "C" "B" "C" "A"
c5  "1" "C" "A" "C" "B"
```

How can I make replacements for the entire dataset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not include the key in the data structure as an observation (row). Conceptually it doesn't belong there. You should also work with a matrix instead of a data.frame.

```
x <- as.matrix(x)
key <- x[1,]
x <- x[-1,]

x[x == "M"] <- NA

#matrices are filled by column, 
#thus we need to transpose
#unary plus turns the logical matrix into an integer matrix
y <- +(t(t(x) == key))
#   q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
#c1 NA NA NA NA NA
#c2 NA NA NA NA NA
#c3  0  1  1  0  1
#c4  0  1  0  0  1
#c5  1  1  1  0  0
```

Note that I corrected typos in your data.

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr to mutate all columns:

```
library(dplyr)

# after the NA inputation step

x %>%
  mutate_all(funs(ifelse(row_number(.) == 1, 
                         as.character(.), # leave first row unchanged
                         as.numeric(toupper(.) == first(.))))) #compare subsequent rows with first

    q1   q2   q3   q4   q5
1    A    C    A    B    A
2 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
4    0    1    1    0    1
5    0    1    0    0    1
6    1    1    1    0    0
```

(Note: the sample data includes answers in both upper & lower case, so I assumed that both inputs were permitted by the computer. If that's not the case & all answers are in upper case, the `toupper()` part can be skipped.)

Comment: That was a typo, all are upper case. This works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Note that all values in the result will be character. That could matter for subsequent steps of the data analysis.

Answer (score -1):

With ifelse function you could do:

```
#When working with character data, take note of this option stringsAsFactors=FALSE
# Candidate c4 data has lower key C, corrected it below


x = data.frame(rbind(c("A","C","A","B","A"),
                    c("M","M","M","M","M"),
                    c("M","M","M","M","M"),
                    c("C","C","A","C","A"),
                    c("c","c","B","C","A"),
                    c("A","C","A","C","B")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)



#all upper case                 
x = sapply(x,toupper)   

colnames(x) = c("q1","q2","q3","q4","q5")
rownames(x) = c("key","c1","c2","c3","c4","c5")

#replace M's
x[x == "M"] = NA



#Match each row with key vector x[1,], repeated 5 time to match number of rows of original dataset


x[-1,] = ifelse(x[-1,] == matrix(rep(as.matrix(x[1,]),5),nrow=5,byrow=TRUE),1,0)

x

#    q1  q2  q3  q4  q5 
#key "A" "C" "A" "B" "A"
#c1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
#c2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
#c3  "0" "1" "1" "0" "1"
#c4  "0" "1" "0" "0" "1"
#c5  "1" "1" "1" "0" "0"
```

Comment: In the actual scenario size of the dataset is unknown, it could be 10,000 candidates and 1000 questions. Hence 5  must be replaced with nrow(x)-1. 

x[-1,] = ifelse(x[-1,] == matrix(rep(as.matrix(x[1,]),nrow(x)-1,nrow=nrow(x)-1,byrow=TRUE),1,0)